# A design conundrum : minimal client code vs polymorphic design

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am handling several categories of food, catagorized as

- non-cooked meat
- cooked meat
- other food not of the two previous categories

where meat can be pork or beef meat.

Functionally I can characterize in which of the three previous food categories food is (including knowing if the meat is beef or pork if the food is not `other`) thank to a `int ID`. Then I can treat the food by outputting some characteristics of it at a given row of a some given array.

In terms of code, I would like to be able to write something like :

```
// client code
Food SomeFood = new Food(ID); // int ID is given
SomeFood.FillTo(thearray, therow); // where object[,] thearray has to be filled and int therow is the row to be filled
```

where `FillTo` depends on the type of food (cooked of not + type of meat included).

Of course I could design one an only "client" class `Food` wrapping all the info such that for `SomeFood` `FillTo` fills infos to `thearray` according to the type of `SomeFood`, but I don't want to do this.

I would like to define a class hierarchy as follows : a base `Food` class from which derive `Meat` and `CookedMeat` classes such that the non-(cooked or not)-meat case would be handled by the base class `Food`, the two others cases being handled by derived classes, the type of meat being handled by an enum member common to the two derived classes.

My problem is the following : I feel that wanting to write a minimal client code as the one above implies necessarily that I don't need a class hierarchy design, and that if I want a class hierarchy designed, then I am forced to write to decouple the determination of the type of food by an ID and that I have then, according to it, to instanciate the right type of food :

```
// more verbose client code
// int ID is given
ATypeOfFood = gettypefrom(ID);
if (TypeOfFood.Other == ATypeOfFood)
{
    AFood = new OtherFood(ID);
    OtherFood.FillTo(thearray, therow);
}
else if (TypeOfFood.CookedMeat == ATypeOfFood)
{
    AFood = new CookedMeat(ID);
    OtherFood.FillTo(thearray, therow);
}
// etc etc ...
```

Am I wrong ?

Is it possible to encompass somehow the `Food AFood = new ADerivedClass(ID)` inside the base class `Food` ? Or even outside through a setting function ? (I can see how to do this with pointers in `c++`, but not in `c#` as one cannot instantiate base class before setting it.)

*Remark.* The `c#` tag is there because I am into doing this in a `c#` language project, language I am new to and that I am learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, but let's try.

First of all, this is of course about balancing. You don't want to sacrifice "users have a clean API to program against" for "my library is super-well defined regarding OOP".

Guiding mantras for "good APIs" - they

- make it easy to do the right thing, and hard to do the wrong thing
- should be prepared for *future* visions

Meaning: when implementing a solution, you remember about [yagni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) - you avoid implementing something that you don't need today. But: when you provide an API to "clients", then you don't want to *break* them with future releases.

Thus: you have to step back and *clarify* for yourself what the intended *use cases* are - from the perspective of the **users** of your API. You make sure that your API allows them to write expressive, robust code to do what they have to do. And to a certain degree, you want to be prepared for future changes that you maybe can foresee today already.

Coming from there:

- derive an object model that is helpful to the users of your API
- when you got a clear picture of that, then look into the question how to implement that model in a nice, clean fashion